# Что посоветуете как узнать какое номер присвоит база данных при добавление нового id

Tags: php, mysql

Что посоветуете, как узнать, какое номер присвоит поле id в базе данных при добавление нового id. Я добавляю новые данные из формы в таблицу, далее мне нужно перебросить на другую страницу с id которое присвоила система, есть какое-нибудь решение которое позволяет получить данную информацию в php ?

Comment: добавляете запись и после этого получаете ее id  помощью last_insert_id() или аналогичных функций

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в качестве идентификатора вы используете `auto_increment`, то получить его значение можно с помощью функции [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) и соответствующего запроса `select last_insert_id();`.

- При работе с mysql через устаревшее расширение `mysql_*` вы можете использовать функцию [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php)
- При работе с БД с помощью `mysqli` вы можете использовать свойство [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php) или функцию [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php)
- при работе через PDO вы можете использовать [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: В этом случае Вы получите id последней добавленной записи в таблицу, а не id записи, добавленной Вами только что. В общем случае это разные записи, поскольку за время повторного обращения к БД для получения LAST_INSERT_ID могло быть выполнено ещё несколько транзакций.

На мой взгляд, если работать в два запроса - нужно сначала спросить у генератора следующий ID, а потом использовать его при INSERTе.

Если в один запрос - то делать INSERT с помощью хранимой процедуры на стороне БД, которая инкапсулирует эту же самую логику. Экономия лишнего сетевого обращения и логика на своём месте.

Comment: В комментарии ограничение на количество символов, поэтому всё не влезло. Для проверки высказанной гипотезы достаточно провести нагрузочное тестирование с сотней одновременных запросов.

Comment: @iTollu я думаю вы должны быть в состоянии в своем коде знать, выполняются ли _в вашем текущем подключении_ прочие одновременные запросы. Очевидно, что если операции insret для текущего подключения проводятся асинхронно, или влекут за собой вызов триггеров или еще чего, что может повлиять на возвращаемое значение,то этот способ не подходит. Но если у вас синхронный код, и сразу после запроса на вставку вы извлекаете полученный ID то проблемы быть никакой не должно. Несколько других транзакций, выполненных другими пользователями, не повлияют на результат, т.к. он относится к подключению.

Comment: но т.к. пхп в однопоточен, то мне не совсем ясно, какие еще могут произойти транзакции между двумя последовательным запросами на `insert` и получения `id`

Comment: Согласен, в документации MySQL нашёл: The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.